# the Constantinople upgrade activates at Block #7280000

Tags: go-ethereum

Should I upgrade to the latest go-etherum before the Constantinople upgrade activates at Block #7280000? If I do not upgrade, will it affect my node to do transactions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You need to have your Ethereum node up-to-date or it will get stuck of last non-forking block.

Comment: Please mark the answer as the correct if you feel it is correct :) The tick icon.